# How do I submit a GET Request with an Auth Key and Path in Dart?

Tags: api, http, dart

I have been trying to use  Httpclient to access an API. It requires me to submit a key to authenticate but cant seem to get the right combination to go through. So my question is how do I specifically pass the authentication key and path in my headers?

Comment: "submit a key" is way too unspecific. What key and what path? What API. This question does not provide any information that could be used to diagnose the problem or to make suggestions.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am trying to make GET requests with this API: https://www.thebluealliance.com/apidocs/v3 sorry for not being specific. Not really sure what methods to call in order to successfully return the JSON.